# apk file expansion - Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, apk-expansion-files

Im developing an android app using phonegap. An app which plays the audio tracks from local. The HTML files along with the JS, CSS, and the local audio tracks are placed in the assets folder.There are a huge number of audio tracks, totally comes around 200Mb. But the apk file upload limits to 50MB. I saw this approach  [APK Expansion File](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html).
And they tell to convert the media files to *.obb format. My doubt is, should I convert the entire assets folder into *.obb format or should i convert only the media folder inside the asset folder?